# PHP Object being passed to class, not being accepted

Tags: php, class, object

I have a database class that has a series of functions in it, and I have a Main class that has the dependencies injected into it with other classes such as Users, Posts, Pages etc extending off of it.

This is the main class that has the database dependency injected into it.

```
class Main {    
    protected $database;
    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->database = $db;
    }
}

$database = new  Database($database_host, $database_user, $database_password, $database_name);
$init = new Main($database);
```

And then, this is the Users class I'm extending off of it.

```
class Users extends Main {
    public function login() {
        System::redirect('login.php');
    }

    public function view($username) {    
        $user = $this->database->findFirst('Users', 'username', $username);

        if($user) {
            print_r($user);
        } else {
            echo "User not found!";
        }    
    }

}
```

But, whenever trying to call the view function for the User class, I'm getting this error **Catchable fatal error:** Argument 1 passed to Main::__construct() must be an instance of Database, none given. And, if I remove the Database keyword from the _*construct parameters, I get this error instead **Warning:** Missing argument 1 for Main::*_construct().

If I pass a variable to the User class from main class it works, but not if I'm trying to pass the Database object, I just can't work out why.

The User class is instantiated via a router with no parameters passed to it.

Comment: How do you instantiate class `User` ? It need to accept the same parameters as it's parent. You only show how you are instnatiating the base one

Comment: Does your database class return an instance of the database connection.  Try a car dump to see what it contains

Comment: @RoyalBg I updated the question. The User class is instantiated via a router with no parameters passed to it.

Comment: @kabuto178 No, I don't believe so, could you please provide an example of doing so?

Comment: _The User class is instantiated (...) with no parameters passed to it_ - so how can you expect it to work? The constructor expects a `Database` class object. It's obvious.

Comment: @matewka Because it was extended from the Main class, would I need to pass the database to both the Main and User class individually?

Comment: When you create an object of class `User` you should pass it a `Database` object, like this: `$db = new Database($some_params); $user = new User($db);`

Comment: @ablshd You are not instantiating both objects, you are instantiating the child class and inheriting functionality from the parent class. Because you have not defined an explicit constructor in your `Users` class you are inheriting `Main`'s constructor, which expects the arguments you defined, namely the `Database` object. Here's an eval of what you are doing, as per the comment by @matewka above. Note the second invocation is throwing an error, which is what is happening in your code: https://eval.in/104527

Comment: Your class design breaks both Liskov Substitution Principle and Single-Responsibility Principle at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `$database` variable in the `Main` class **static**. Then you need to initialize it only once:

```
class Main {    
    static $database = null;
    public function __construct($db = null)
    {
        if (self::$database === null && $db instanceof Database) {
            self::$database = $db;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It breaks encapsulation since state of a `$database` can be altered after instantiation. And since a class cannot/should not work without a database, why do you also expect a $db to be a `null`? Looks like a code smell. Therefore +0

Comment: @djay how come? Constructor instatiates the `self::$database` only when it's null. Is there any need to _re-instantiate_ the object with some other credentials (host, db, user, etc.)?

Comment: Constructor should not be dealing with instantiation logic. It should accept a prepared/configured database instance as an argument. That's what **Dependency Injection** is about. What you're doing in constructor is called **Lazy initialization** and since then it breaks the **Single-Responsibility Principle** (because it has two reasons to change)

Comment: @djay wow! That's hell of an explanation. Thanks! I think you're absoultely right about this. Moreover, I think this very issue mentioned in the question should be handled some completely other way. I think `Database` class should be a _singleton_ in the first place. Then, I don't think there's any need to pass it to the constructor in every instance of `Main` or its descendants.

Comment: The very first you have to understand is that `database` is a part of storage logic **and only**. And since then a database instance should only be used inside classes that **do abstract** storage logic. (*aka Data Mapper Pattern*) And yes you're right - there's no need to pass a database instance to every class that abstracts storage logic. This should be passed automatically by a factory, like `$mapperFactory->build('Foo')` and then a factory itself should be injected to the classes that deal with storage logic. That's what **DiP** principle is about.

Comment: As for a Singleton - technically there's no difference between a Singleton and a global variable - because they **were not** injected as an argument,
and both come from global scope. Therefore you end up with global state, that makes Unit-tests very complex (Since an instance of database cannot be substituted with a mocked database object at runtime) and plus your Database singleton becomes tightly-coupled. That's why it would be much better to avoid singletons.

Answer (score 0):

The class User extends Main and therefore it inherits the __construct function of the Main class.

You can't instantiate the User class without passing its dependency, the Database instance.

```
$database = new  Database($database_host, $database_user, $database_password, $database_name);
$user = new User($database);
```

However, you can do it like matewka hinted:

```
class Main {    
static $database = null;
  public function __construct($db = null)
  {
      if (self::$database === null && $db instanceof Database) {
          self::$database = $db;
      }
  }
}

class User extends Main{

 function test()
 {
    return parent::$database->test();
 }
}
class Database{

 function test()
 {
    return "DATABASE_TEST";
 }
}

$db = new Database();
$main = new Main($db);


$user = new User();
var_dump($user->test());
```

Answer (score 0):

As clearly noted in the other answers/comments you are not passing the expected dependency into your `Users` class to the `__construct()` method it inherits from `Main`.

In other words, `Users` expects to be instantiated in the same manner as `Main`; i.e:

```
$database = new Database();
$users = new Users($database);
```

However, I would like to add some detail because constructors in PHP are a little different to other methods when you are defining inheritance relationships between classes, and I think it's worth knowing.

Using inheritance, you can of course override a parent's method in an inheriting class, with a specific caveat in PHP: if you don't match the argument signature of the overridden method you trigger a `E_STRICT` warning. This is not a showstopper but it's best avoided when endeavouring to write stable robust code:

> `E_STRICT` Enable to have PHP suggest changes to your code which will ensure the best interoperability and forward compatibility of your code. [Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

An example:

```
class Dependency
{
    // implement
}

class Foo
{
    function doSomething(Dependency $dep)
    {
        // parent implementation
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    function doSomething()
    {
        // overridden implementation
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->doSomething();
```

If you run this code or lint it on the command line with `php -l` you'll get something like:

> `PHP Strict standards:  Declaration of Bar::doSomething() should be compatible with Foo::doSomething(Dependency $dep) in cons.php on line 22`

The reason why I am pointing this out is because this *does not apply* to `__construct`:

> Unlike with other methods, PHP will not generate an E_STRICT level error message when __construct() is overridden with different parameters than the parent __construct() method has. [Source (#Example 1)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

So you can safely override `__construct` in an inheriting class and define a different argument signature.

This example is completely valid:

```
class Foo
{
    function __construct(Dependency $dep)
    {
        // parent constructor
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // overridden constructor
    }
}

$bar = new Bar();
```

Of course, this is dangerous because in the highly likely event inheriting class `Bar` calls code that relies on `Dependency` you're going to get an error because you never instantiated or passed the dependency.

So you really should ensure the `Dependency` in the case above is passed to the parent class. So you are right back where you started, passing the dependency in the constructor, *or* doing the following, using the [`parent` keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) to call the parent's `__construct` method:

```
class Bar extends Main
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // call the Main constructor and ensure
        // its expected dependencies are satisfied
        parent::__construct(new Dependency());
    }
}
```

However, best practice dictates that you should pass dependencies into your object instead of instantiating them in your classes, a.k.a [dependency injection](https://www.php.net/__destruct). So we arrive back at the original solution provided by the other answers :)

```
$database = new Database();
$users = new Users($database);
```

Allowing overriding of `__construct` with different method signatures simply allows greater flexibility when defining classes - you might have am inheriting class that requires more information to be instantiated. For a (ridiculously contrived) example:

```
class Person
{
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        // implement
    }
}

class Prisoner extends Person
{
    public function __construct($name, $number)
    {
        // implement
    }
}

$p1 = new Person('Darragh');
$p2 = new Prisoner('Darragh', 'I AM NOT A NUMBER!');
```

I am pointing this out because `__construct` is actually quite flexible, if you find yourself in a situation where you want to instantiate an inheriting class with different arguments to the parent, you can, but with the *big caveat* that you must somehow ensure that you satisfy **all** expected dependencies of the parent class.

Hope this helps :)